# Issue with pc giving DRAM/CPU debug lights

Tags: memory, cpu, bios, motherboard, desktop-computer

I am having an issue with my pc where it wont post and I get CPU and DRAM debug lights. My motherboard is an `MSI B450-A PRO MAX`.

I have updated the BIOS to the latest version, before doing this update I would just get a CPU light, now I get both.

When attempting to boot this is the order of the lights:

1. When power button is pressed it turns on all lights except CPU, then briefly changes to the CPU light.
2. After about half a second it changes to the DRAM light.
3. After about 5 seconds it changes back to the CPU light. (This only happens sometimes.)
4. If the CPU light doesn't come back on the DRAM light stays on indefinitely.

The PC won't post or even wake up the monitor.

I am using the 2 RAM slots marked first on the silkscreen although I have the same issue with 4 sticks

After leaving the computer on for a day the GPU doesn't get hot at all, from touching the back I estimate it to be at maybe 30 degrees so it seems its not doing much.

Num lock responds but caps and scroll do not.

EDIT: I just went to reseat the CPU as comments suggested and discovered that one of the mounting holes on the backplate was stripped putting uneven pressure on the CPU. I will buy a new backplate and update this if it fixes my problem!

Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: What slots are you using for the RAM? I had confusion with this same board. I would get the CPU light and RAM light but then the CPU light would turn off. When it's first booting the lights will display even though everything was fine. Once it starts booting into Windows the lights will turn off. The DRAM light would stay on because the board manual says to use DIMMA2 for 1 stick, DIMMA2 and DIMMB2 if you have two sticks. I was using DIMMA1 and DIMMB1. Once I switched that all of the lights would turn off roughly 5-10 seconds after booting.

Comment: @DrZoo I am using the ram slots marked as first on the silkscreen also the computer won't even post

Comment: I'll expand on my previous comment by saying I have the same issue with 4 sticks

Comment: With the CPU light sometimes coming on and staying, have you reseated your CPU too and possible bent pins?

Comment: i will try that thanks

Comment: @DrZoo I just went to reseat the CPU and I found that one of the screw holes for mounting the cooler was stripped, thanks for the suggestion or I may never have found it!